# Программа для написания программ на С++

Tags: c++, ide

В какой программе собственно программируют? Я считал что это делается в Microsoft Visual Studio. И вот я дорвался до 2010 версии, а она не хочет дебажить мой код написанный с учебника. Может нужно ещё что-то настроитьв самой студии или использовать другую среду?

Comment: Приведите пример кода и напишите что вы делаете, что хотите получить и что именно не получается.

Comment: #include <iostrem>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout <<"That's my first prog!";
 return 0;
}

Comment: При этом кнопка дебаг старт остаётся неактивной и серой.

Comment: Вероятнее всего Вы не создали соответсвующий проект в студии. Посмотрите [тут](http://www.youngcoder.net/2013/07/visual-studio-2010.html)

Comment: Всё сделал. Теперь он матирится при старте дебага: проект устарел и какая-то ошибка при составлении. Екзешник не создаётся. Все фреймворки стоят.

Comment: А какая именно ошибка мы должны угадать? Может, вы опечатались, а может, создали проект на C# и скопировали туда код на C++, кто знает?

Answer (score 6):

Зависит от операционной системы.

**Под Windows**:

- MS Visual Studio
- NetBeans
- Eclipse
- Qt Creator
- Emacs (а как же без него!)
- JetBrains CLion (*обновлено, спасибо ixSci*);

**Под Linux**:

- всё то же, кроме MS Visual Studio

**Под Mac OS X** (*обновлено, спасибо ixSci*):

- XCode
- AppCode

Под Linux часто вообще не используется никакая IDE-среда разработки,
а используется просто отдельный компилятор, `gcc` или `clang`
и обычный текстовый редактор, типа Vim.

В этом случае написание и компиляция простейшей программы выглядит так:

```
vim hello-world.c
gcc -o hello-world hello-world.c
```

Но это только в самом простейшем случае. В реальности же вы очень быстро приходите к необходимости использования программ сборки, отладки, анализа кода и так далее.

Программы сборки занимают очень важное место в инструментарии разработчика. Без них редко себе можно представить написание сколь-нибудь сложной программы.
Классической программой сборки являеися *make* (и его различные клоны-реализации в различных системах, например, *cmake*), но сейчас набирают популярность и ряд других программ.

Итак, универсальные программы для сборки (есть и специфичные, использующиеся только в некоторых случаях):

- **make** + **autotools**;
- **SCons** — сравнительно медленная, но мощная программа сборки; написана на Python;
- **Waf** — другая программа сбоки на Python, но отличающаяся от SCons высокой скоростью;
- **ninja** — сверхбыстрая сборочная программа на Си++, как правило используется в сочетании с более высокоуровневыми программами, такими как **CMake**, **gyp** или даже **SCons**.

Пример простейшего Makefile'а и его использование:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g
RM      = rm -f


default: all

all: Hello

hello: Hello.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o hello hello.c

clean veryclean:
    $(RM) hello
```

Использование:

```
$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
```

Comment: CLion забыли! Ну и под OS X: XCode, AppCode

Comment: make -- основной инструмент упомянуть забыли. / А IDE (для написания кода вполне достаточно Emacs в многооконной среде) я, например, вообще не использую.

Comment: @avp: Почему, я же написал про программы сборки? Просто я их не перечислял. Надо бы перечислить, наверное.

Comment: @avp: Спасибо за идею написать побольше про make и другие средства сборки. Добавил их в ответ!

Answer (score 0):

На сайте microsoft есть актуальная версия [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/products/free-developer-offers-vs.aspx) , полностью бесплатная и способная в полной мере удовлетворить ВСЕ нужды начинающего разработчика .

Так же есть подробнейшая [справка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/dd831853.aspx) по работе с этой IDE , на русском языке .Так же есть [сайт разработчиков](https://dev.windows.com/ru-ru/develop) под платформу Windows. В общем то большей информации вам еще достаточно долго не потребуется .

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, просто напросто нет одной единственной, общепринятой IDE (*в вашем случае программы в которой программируют*), как предназначенную конкретно под C++ (*разве что компилятор данного языка от его создателей, если так можно выразиться*).

Во-вторых, я так понимаю вы поставили VisualStudio, так как в именно в ней разбирает примеры автор книги, если да, то я бы посоветовал изучить оффициальную документацию для вашей IDE, и понять как она устроена, какие настройки за что отвечают, как в ней работать с тем же debug - ром. Это тот минимум нужный начинающему программисту чтобы осознавать что он делает!

Ну если же вы просто поставили VisualStudio по советам интернет сообществ, то ничего плохого нет, вам опять же надо просто понять как она устроена и настроить её под ваши нужды.

В-третьих, я бы посоветовал вам попробовать что-нибудь попроще, а именно: wxDev C++, но опять же выбор IDE зависит от ваших пожеланий и умений, но судя по заданному вопросу я бы склонился к IDE по проще чем VisualStudio, так как она громоздка и разбирательство во всех её аспектах и тонкостях напрочь отбивает желание обучиться программированию.

Comment: Не злоупотребляйте разметкой.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же это **notepad++**. У него даже есть "++" в названии.

А вообще для написания кода можно использовать любой текстовый редактор. Если использовать **CMake**, то для написания скриптов сборки тоже нужен только текстовый редактор.
Отлаживать код можно и в Visual Studio, для этого CMake умеет генерировать файлы проекта MSVS.